# How to change this javascript function to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, character-limit

I have this code to work as character limiter for CKEditor, but its old and i dont know why does not work when i use Jquery librarie in the same web site

```
window.onload = function() {
        CKEDITOR.instances.aqui.on( 'key', function() {
            var str = CKEDITOR.instances.aqui.getData();
            var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig
            ,   result = str.replace(regex, "");
            if (result.length > 50) {
                CKEDITOR.instances.aqui.setData(str);
            }
        } );
    };
```

i want to update the code to use Jquery, but i dont know to much of jquery and i think if i use this function (replace, remove or text that) it will be more usefull

The code works if you dont add the Jquery library.

Comment: There's nothing in that code that should be affected by adding jQuery to the page; something *else* is going on in something you haven't shown.

Comment: If pure javascript is broken, chances are that transforming it into jQuery won't magically make it work. I guess you have some debugging in prospect.

Comment: This code works if you dont put the Jquery library

Comment: Are you saying this code DOESNT'T work when you add the jQuery library?

Comment: No, i dont say, I confirm, i have tried 3 times and when I add this line <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"/> it doesent work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using CKEditor, you may need the jQuery Adapter to make it work. 
You will need include source files like this on your header

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="adapters/jquery.js"></script>
```

Please see details [here](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_jquery)

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the windows.onload event handler and that *should* be the cause of your problem.

Try instead the following change in your code:

```
// previous
window.onload = function() { /* your code here */ };

// suggestion
$( document ).ready(function() { /* your code here */ });
```